# JIRA expand = changelog not working

Tags: api, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to query jira for data with folowing jql:

```
 $jql_options = array(
        "jql" => $jql,
        "startAt" => 0,
        "maxResults" => 1,
        "validateQuery" => false,
        "fields" => array(
            "summary",
            "status",
            "assignee"
        ),
        "expand" => "changelog"
    );
```

And i get this error:

```
string(282) "{"errorMessages":["Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@464d8928; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.search.SearchRequestBean[\"expand\"])"]}"
```

I understand it's an error with "expand" => "changelog" but on their site they present an requeste representation like mine.

Can u give me some advice? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems i was reading the rest api documentation wrong.

"expand" option was available only in get request.

I appended jql data in url + "&expand=changelog" and other options i send them in post!

```
    $jql_options = array(
        "startAt" => 0,
        "maxResults" => 1,
        "validateQuery" => false,
        "fields" => array(
            "key"
        )
    );

    $data = json_encode($jql_options);

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $this->jiraURL . "/rest/api/latest/search?jql=" .urlencode($jql) . "&expand=changelog",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($this->username.":".$this->password),
            'Content-type: application/json') ,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
    );
```